# Unable to replace the string with replace(). Can anyone show me the error in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The thing I want to do is replace a string (like 'cat is zot') with the alphabet's position ('a' = '1', 'b' = '2', 'e' = '5', 'z' = '26'). When I use replace(), I get the desired output, but if I put it in a loop, I get my original string back.

code:-

```
text = 'cat is zot'
for x in range(1,27):
        if x == 1:            
                new = text.replace(chr(ord('a')), str(x))
        else:
                new = text.replace(chr(ord('a')+x), str(x))
print(text)
print(new)
```

Output:-

```
'cat is zot'
'cat is zot'
```

Desired Output:-
'3120 919 261520'

Comment: add a breakpoint before for statement, then debug you'll find the replace only works in single loop and next loop, new will change back to original text

Answer (score 0):

1. on every iteration of your loop, you replace one character *in the original string*, but since you never modify that original string... the replacements don't accumulate.
2. your offsets are off by one, so instread of replacing *b* by 2 *c* by 2, which also explains why you never get any change despite your string containing a `z`: on the last iteration you try to replace `chr(ord('a')+26='{'`. So your last iteration is `new = text.replace('{', '26')` which does nothing, and since you've never updated `text it's the same as` new = text`, which is the same as` new = 'cat is zot'`.

Comment: Thank you @Masklinn. I took your and Pax's advice to correct my code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for each loop you are replacing the `text = 'cat is zot'`. So during each loop you replace a alphabet to string and back to new. At the last loop, you end up with character `chr(ord('z')+1)` which doesn't exist in your string and you end up with `new=text` exact string.

The solution here would be to use `new` to replace the string and store it back to new like:

```
for x in range(1,26):
    if x==1:
        new = text.replace('a', str(x))
    else:
        new = new.replace(chr(ord('a')+x-1), str(x))
```

Here I used -1 because, you begin with 1. For character b, it jumps to a+2; intended for c.

Alternate solution is using list comprehension like:

```
''.join([' ' if x==' ' else str(ord(x)-ord('a')+1) for x in text])
```

Comment: FWIW you don't need the square brackets (`join` takes arbitrary iterables just fine), and it might be better to check if `x` is in `string.ascii_lowercase` than special-case `' '`.

Comment: Thank you @Pax. I see my mistake. Corrected my code and it works as intended.